# Selecionar os valores recebidos da matriz via POST (Codeigniter)

Tags: php

Eu tenho o seguinte:

```
-- HTML --
<form class="" id="quiz_form" action="" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="mcq-<?php echo $quiz_question['id']; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $key2+1; ?>">
   <input type="checkbox" name="discursive-<?php echo $quiz_question['id']; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $key2+1; ?>">
   <input type="button" onclick="submitQuiz()">
</form>

function submitQuiz() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'home/submit_av',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('form#quiz_form').serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#quiz-body').hide();
            $('#quiz-result').html(response);
        }
    });
}

-- Content php receive data post --
public function submit_av($from = "") {
        $data['question_mcq'] = json_encode($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
        $data['question_discursive'] = json_encode($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
        $this->db->insert('av_results', $data);
    }
```

No banco de dados está salvando assim:

```
{"discursive-8":["My answer 1"],"mcq-7":["1"],"discursive-9":["My answer 2"]}
```

Preciso separar esses arrays e colocá-los em seus respectivos campos.

Como posso identificar dentro de `json_encode` se é" **mcq** "ou" **discursive** "?

Preciso salvar desta forma:

Coluna: **question_mcq**

```
{"mcq-7":["1"]}
```

Coluna: **question_discursive**

```
{"discursive-8":["My answer 1"],"discursive-9":["My answer 2"]}
```

É importante lembrar que os valores `name` e `value` do input não são os mesmos, eles mudam dentro de um `foreach`.